# Enumerate UVC Extension Units

Tags: windows, usb, directshow

I am trying to access the extension unit properties just as described here: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff565158(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff565158%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
ExtensionProp.Property.Set = PROPSETID_VIDCAP_EXTENSION_UNIT;
ExtensionProp.Property.Id = KSPROPERTY_EXTENSION_UNIT_INFO;
ExtensionProp.Property.Flags = KSPROPERTY_TYPE_GET | 
                               KSPROPERTY_TYPE_TOPOLOGY;
ExtensionProp.NodeId = m_dwNodeId;

hr = m_pKsControl->KsProperty(
    (PKSPROPERTY) &ExtensionProp,
    sizeof(ExtensionProp),
    NULL,
    0,
    &ulBytesReturned);
```

However, here we must know the extension unit GUID (PROPSETID_VIDCAP_EXTENSION_UNIT in the code above) that is the same that the GUID from the extension unit descriptor. What I want to do is to enumerate all the extension unit GUIDs in the system, or, somehow else retrieve that GUIDs without having to hardcode them. Is this possible? Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the extension unit guid with the `usbview.exe` tool.
Check this on how to install it: https://www.techrepublic.com/article/tracking-down-usb-devices-in-windows-10-with-microsofts-usb-device-viewer/